# How to get data from JPA Repository with where and or?

Tags: spring, repository, spring-data-jpa

I have code like this:

```
List<SomeEntity> a = aRepo.findAll();
for(.......) {
  tmpData = tmpRepo.findOneByParam1AndParam2And... (param1, param2, ...)
  ...
}
```

The problem is that if I need to iterate 1,000 times I will lose a lot of time. How can I get all data of tmpRepo that I need? Something like:

```
get all data from tmpRepo where (Param1 = value1 and Param2 = value2 ...) or (Param1 = value11 and Param2 = value12 ...)
```

Maybe I can pass a list as an argument?

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem with Spring data a feel weeks ago. 
I use Specification to resolve my problem. I believe you can too.

Look at this tutorial about "Advanced queries."

https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/